# set ip node from inventory to default/main.yaml

Tags: ansible

Repository: https://github.com/patsevanton/ansible-role-patroni-question
Inventory:

```
[all]
node1 ansible_host=192.168.88.95
node2 ansible_host=192.168.88.96
node3 ansible_host=192.168.88.97

[patroni]
node1
node2
node3
```

Default main yaml file
https://github.com/patsevanton/ansible-role-patroni-question/blob/master/defaults/main.yml#L115
[image]
[image]

How set ip node from inventory to default/main.yaml ?
This is not template! This is default/main.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

The very fact that it is in `defaults` for that role means it is **designed** to be overriden by you.

Thus:

```
- hosts: patroni
  roles:
  - patsevanton.patroni-question
    vars:
      patroni_bootstrap_pg_hba: >-
        [
        {%- set thing = { "type": "host", "database": "replication", "user": patroni_replication_username, "method": "md5" } -%}
        {%- for h, v in dict(hostvars).items() -%}
        {%- set _ = thing.update({"address": v.ansible_host}) -%}
        {{ "" if loop.first else "," }}
        {{ thing | to_json }}
        {%- endfor -%}
        ]
```

Pulling the `pg_hba` definition outside the role means you now have to specify `replication_username`, too, because the outer playbook cannot (easily) look down into the role to grab the existing default. *C'est la vie* when using a role with poorly designed defaults.